# R: Debug tensorflow

Tags: r, tensorflow

I'm trying to get hands on tensorflow on R. So this is my script so far:

```
library(tensorflow)
library(tfdatasets)
library(keras)
tf$executing_eagerly()


c(c(x_train, y_train), c(x_test, y_test)) %<-% keras::dataset_mnist("/home/christ/mnist.npz")
x_train %<>% { . / 255 }
x_test  %<>% { . / 255 }
                                                    
                                                    
train_ds <- list(x_train, y_train) %>%
  tensor_slices_dataset() %>%
  dataset_shuffle(10000) %>%
  dataset_batch(32)

test_ds <- list(x_test, y_test) %>%
  tensor_slices_dataset() %>%
  dataset_batch(32)

my_model <- new_model_class(
  classname = "MyModel",
  initialize = function(...) {
    super$initialize()
    self$conv1 <- layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3,
                                activation = 'relu')
    self$flatten <- layer_flatten()
    self$d1 <- layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')
    self$d2 <- layer_dense(units = 10)
  },
  call = function(inputs) {
    browser()
    inputs %>%
      tf$expand_dims(3L) %>%
      self$conv1() %>%
      self$flatten() %>%
      self$d1() %>%
      self$d2()
  }
)

# Create an instance of the model
model <- my_model()

loss_object <- loss_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(from_logits = TRUE)
optimizer <- optimizer_adam()
train_loss <- metric_mean(name = "train_loss")
train_accuracy <- metric_sparse_categorical_accuracy(name = "train_accuracy")

test_loss <- metric_mean(name = "test_loss")
test_accuracy <- metric_sparse_categorical_accuracy(name = "test_accuracy")


train_step <- function(images, labels) {
  with(tf$GradientTape() %as% tape, {
    # training = TRUE is only needed if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    predictions <- model(images, training = TRUE)
    loss <- loss_object(labels, predictions)
  })
  gradients <- tape$gradient(loss, model$trainable_variables)
  optimizer$apply_gradients(zip_lists(gradients, model$trainable_variables))
  train_loss(loss)
  train_accuracy(labels, predictions)
}

train <- tf_function(function(train_ds) {
  for (batch in train_ds) {
    c(images, labels) %<-% batch
    train_step(images, labels)
  }
})


test_step <- function(images, labels) {
  # training = FALSE is only needed if there are layers with different
  # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
  predictions <- model(images, training = FALSE)
  t_loss <- loss_object(labels, predictions)
  test_loss(t_loss)
  test_accuracy(labels, predictions)
}

test <- tf_function(function(test_ds) {
  for (batch in test_ds) {
    c(images, labels) %<-% batch
    test_step(images, labels)
  }
})

reset_metrics <- function() {
  for (metric in list(train_loss, train_accuracy,
                      test_loss, test_accuracy))
    metric$reset_states()
}

EPOCHS <- 1
for (epoch in seq_len(EPOCHS)) {
  # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
  reset_metrics()
  train(train_ds)
  test(test_ds)
  cat(sprintf('Epoch %d', epoch), "\n")
  cat(sprintf('Loss: %f', train_loss$result()), "\n")
  cat(sprintf('Accuracy: %f', train_accuracy$result() * 100), "\n")
  cat(sprintf('Test Loss: %f', test_loss$result()), "\n")
  cat(sprintf('Test Accuracy: %f', test_accuracy$result() * 100), "\n")
```

I really would like to dig into the process and therefore added a browser in my model evaluation.
So when I start the training, the process is stopped at the breakpoint. However when I try to print the inputs argument, I get

```
inputs
Tensor("my_model/Cast:0", shape=(None, 28, 28), dtype=float32)
inputs$eval()
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`
```

I installed tensorflow 2.12, so I thought that sessions are gone?